# Flask's auth.verify_token doesn't return a JSON response

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

I have a Flask app where I use JWTs for authentication. My code looks like this:

```
@auth.verify_token
@inject
def verify_token(
        token,
        authentication_service: AuthenticationService = Provide[
            Container.authentication_service
        ],
):
    try:
        authentication_service.validate_jwt(token, "audience-value")
    except UnauthorizedRequest as e:
        return handle_errors(e)


@inject
@auth.login_required
@swag_from("./swagger/get_resource.yml")
def get_resources(
        my_service: MyService = Provide[
            Container.my_service
        ],
):
    content = request.json
    member_id = content["memberId"]
    result = my_service.get_resource(member_id)
    return jsonify(result)

def handle_errors(error):
    response = make_response()
    response.data = str(error.to_dict())
    response.content_type = "application/json"
    response.status_code = 401
    return response, response.status_code
```

While `handle_errors` is invoked as expected, the final result I see when I invoke the API is `text/html` instead of `application/json`

```
< HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 19
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Authentication Required"
< Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.9.6
< Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2022 12:56:41 GMT
```

Does the `@auth.verify_token` decorator not allow for any other kind of response? I'd just like to return a JSON response with a message like `Signature expired`, etc. Is there a way I override the default response?

Comment: what package are you using to verify & manage the JWTs? we could probably use the code for @login_required at least

Comment: also, you can try flask's "abort" function instead of make_response() and see if that has the same effect. for example abort(401, str(error.to_dict()))